# Cannot access a disposed object. Transaction

Tags: c#, entity-framework, transactions, transactionscope

We are using Entity Framework and running unit tests within a transaction scope. We were origianally getting the error in the title.

I have managed to isolate the problem some what.

```
using (TransactionScope scope1 = new TransactionScope())
{
    using (TransactionScope scope2 = new TransactionScope())
    {
           // Here there is no code
    }

    using (Entities se = new Entities())
    {
        EntityConnection entityConnection = (EntityConnection)se.Connection;
        DbConnection storeConnection = entityConnection.StoreConnection;

        storeConnection.Open(); // On this line the error occurs

           // Some code that runs a stored procedure
    }
}
```

The error that we are currently getting is  "The operation is not valid for the state of the transaction.."

If I remove transaction scope2, everything works fine.

If I mark scope 2 as an ambient transaction it also works fine.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are creating scope2 without an explicit `TransactionScopeOption` parameter, which yields a default of `TransactionScopeOption.Required`, see section *Remarks* within [`TransactionScope Constructor`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1hfx49zc.aspx)

> This constructor creates a new
>   transaction scope with the transaction
>   scope option equal to  Required. This
>   means that a transaction is required
>   by the new scope and the ambient
>   transaction is used if one already
>   exists. Otherwise, it creates a new
>   transaction before entering the scope.

In your example an ambient `TransactionScope` does indeed exist already (`scope1`), consequently the new nested `TransactionScope` (`scope2`) with implicit parameter `TransactionScopeOption.Required` is using the existing ambient transaction rather than creating a new transaction itself.

However, the implicit transaction semantics of `scope2` are still in place, consequently the existing ambient transaction created by `scope1` is getting aborted because you are not calling [`Complete`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.transactions.transactionscope.complete.aspx) at the end of `scope2`:

> Failing to call this method aborts the
>   transaction, because the transaction
>   manager interprets this as a system
>   failure, or equivalent to an exception
>   thrown within the scope of transaction

Of course the problem goes aways immediately if you remove `scope2` or change its semantics to `TransactionScopeOption.RequiresNew` (meaning *'A new transaction is always created for the scope.'*), because the existing ambient transaction created by `scope1` will not be affected anymore.

See [Implementing an Implicit Transaction using Transaction Scope](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172152.aspx) for more details on this.

Comment: Thanks, that fixed it, I was missing the scope2.complete()

Answer (score 0):

How about this syntax, this is pretty similar , Scope2 is Completed and Disposed of later.

I'm also intermittently seeing the "cannot access a disposed of object 'Transaction' error.
Could it be because I should have created both of these with TransactionScopeOption.RequiresNew instead of TransactionScopeOption.Required?

```
 TransactionOptions rootOptions = new TransactionOptions();
    rootOptions.IsolationLevel = IsolationLevel.ReadCommitted;
    OtherObject.Scope2 = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Required, rootOptions);

    TransactionOptions options = new TransactionOptions();
    options.IsolationLevel = IsolationLevel.ReadCommitted;
    options.Timeout = getTransactionTimeout();
    using (TransactionScope scope = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Required, options))
                {

                                .............
                    scope.Complete();
                }
```

Comment: Hi, I also see that intermitent "Cannot access a disposed object. Object name: 'TransactionScope'. Did you fix also that?