# In which layer would you implement transactions using asp.NET TransactionScope?

Tags: asp.net, architecture, transactions

I have a service, business and data access layer. In which layer should I implement transactions using asp.NET transactionscope? Also, is nesting Transactions a good thing because I had problems with that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Transaction Scope is part of .net not specific to asp.net

We would place the tansaction scope in the business layer. The service layer is more of a facade. If something requires a transaction it should be within a single business operation.

Comment: So a service should never call two business functions? If that were the case and the two functions would need to be called in one transaction, then you would have to define a transactionscope in the service? And then you would have nested transactions... (because the two functions in business layer would already be each in a transactionscope). Or can you easily nest transactionscopes?

Comment: Yes, you can nest transaction scopes, check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1334366/hierarchy-of-transactionscope You need to make sure that you commit each transaction scope when you have nested scopes.

Comment: Well, I tried that, and the inner transaction scope was committed twice, once because of the commit of the inner transaction scope, but also once because of the outer transaction scope. So I would have to look into that again, but is this known behavior?