# TransactionScope functions

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, transactions, transactionscope

Working on Transactions in .net. Had a question on flowing transactions through sub functions. Do I need to use dependent transactions if the object context is common across the sub - methods?

For example, in the following code -  I declare the object context in the constructor of my class (not sure if this is best practice)

```
public class EmployeeRepository
{
    private EmployeeContext ec;        
    public EmployeeRepository()
    {
        objectContext = new EmployeeContext();            
    }       
    public InitTransaction(EmployeeEntity emp1)
    {
         using (TransactionScope transaction = new TransactionScope())
        {
            try
            {   ec.employees.AddObject(emp1);
                SubFunction1();
                ec.SaveChanges();                               
            }
            catch
            {
                //catch 
            }
        }
        //commit the transaction here 
        ec.AcceptAllChanges();
    }

    public SubFunction1()
    {
        //some processing 
        //using same object context
        ec.someother.AddObject(someobject);
        ec.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

I want the subfunctions to be a part of the transactions as well?
In this case should I use a dependent transaction within SubFunction1 even though I am using the same object context? Or Should I add a

```
using (TransactionScope transaction = new TransactionScope());
```

within SubFunction1. Pointers in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Transaction Scopes can be nested (they work similar to the SQL @@TRANCOUNT mechanism), so you could in theory use TransactionScopes in your Repository, e.g. to keep parent : child table relationships ACID, but also in your Business / Service layers as well (e.g. to have a Distributed Transaction across multiple entities, possible across multiple Databases, and even across other resources such as Message Queues and [Transactional file systems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2289395/transactionscope-with-files-in-c).

Note that the [default isolation level of TransactionScope](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dbrowne/archive/2010/05/21/using-new-transactionscope-considered-harmful.aspx) is Read Serializable - this can lead to locking / deadlocks.

Comment: Now my question is - will my code work as is -i.e. Will subfunction1 be part of the transaction if I use the same object context. Should I explicitly begin a transaction in SubFunction1.

Comment: Yes - it will work - SubFunction1 (and anything else called by SubFunction1) will, by default, enlist in your TransactionScope. "Transaction" aware resources such as *Contexts and SQLConnections will enlist automatically.

Comment: Thanks for the input. So no new transactionscope in subfunction1. Also on isolation levels - I am using mysql and have the option of bubbling up failed transactions to the end user (for them to retry). So I thought read serializable would be safe. Should I be changing isolation level to readcommitted?

Comment: also - wanted to add that this app is read/write intensive and not just read heavy...

Comment: Yes, ReadCommitted is usually a better 'default' starting point for most transactions. You can exclude code (e.g. logging) from a encapsulating transaction by starting a new TransactionScope with RequiresNew. But the suggestion is to regard TransactionScope as a 'logical' transaction, at a higher level than your database connections. We usually control the outermost TransactionScope in the Business or Service tiers - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1656986/in-which-layer-would-you-implement-transactions-using-asp-net-transactionscope

Answer (score 0):

You can consider using Dependency Injection to pass around the same `ObjectContext` so you can avoid the `TransactionScope`.

Instead of creating `Context` inside the Repository inject it through constructor.

```
public class EmployeeRepository
{
    private EmployeeContext ec;        
    public EmployeeRepository(EmployeeContext objectContext)
    {
        ec = objectContext;            
    }       

}
```

Take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6987908/what-is-the-best-way-to-instantiate-and-dispose-dbcontext-in-mvc/6990244#6990244)

Comment: Thanks. The code is similar (just omitted it for clarity's sake). I actually have EmployeeRepository implement Idisposable and dispose of the connection. All the ops happen on a wcf rest service.